# How to use Signal R with EF core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, signalr

I am making an MVVM WPF app where multiple users can use different instances of the app. If users make changes to the data in their app the information in all the instances gets updated. I would also like the data to be stored in a SQL database using EF.

I am using this:

```
app.MapPost("UpdateFruits", async (string message, IHubContext<ChatHub> context) =>
{
    await context.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage","FromServer", message);
    return Results.NoContent();
});
```

Background: Before with each client I would poll for data from the server but I recently found out I can possibly use Signal R instead of polling.

1. What are the best practices to pass in a collection of `Fruit`, save it to the database, and also make sure the data gets sent back to all the other user clients that are connected to the server?
2. Is it best practice to send JSON by string and serialize? or is there a way to use the `Fruit` object over Signal R instead of string?

C#

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public List<Leaf>? Leaf{ get; set; }
}

public class Leaf
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public List<Vein>? Vein{ get; set; }
}

public class Vein
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
}
```

Update:

```
app.MapPut("UpdateFruits", async (string message, IHubContext<ChatHub> context, DatabaseContext dbContext) =>
{
    //message(Param) = { "ID":"2","DisplayName":"Fruit","Leaf":null,"State":"Chopped"}

    try
    {
        using var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
        var fruitIn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fruit>(message);

        if (fruitIn == null)
        {
            return Results.NotFound($"Error parsing");
        }

        var dbFruitIn = await dbContext
            .Set<Fruit>()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ID == fruitIn.ID);

        if (dbContext == null)
        {
            return Results.NotFound($"Fruit id: {dbFruitIn.ID}");
        }

        dbFruitIn.DisplayName = fruitIn.DisplayName;
        dbFruitIn.State = fruitIn.State;

        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dbFruitIn);

        await context.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", "FromServer", jsonString); 
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
    }
    return Results.NoContent();
});
```

Comment: I would at least consider putting this in a [transaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions).

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I have added the transaction

Answer (score 0):

You're doing alright from what I can tell, even though your posted code isn't complete.  With more information I could give more specific guidance but basically your `SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);` call will translate `message` to an object on the client.  You don't need the "FromServer" but you should also only send something serializable, meaning that if it has lots of references to other objects, you need to transform it into a type or anonymous object that only contains the parts the client will need.

Comment: I'd actually only send change notifications, so clients can decide whether they need to update their local data with latest version from db. At least for cases, where this makes sense.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods For my use case all clients MUST have the same data, its important that client A state of data is identical. to all other clients e.g. let's say I have 5 apples Client A cuts an apple with ID = 2 the state of apple with ID =2 should be in a state where it cut and no other client should be able to cut apple with ID = 2 even if they click the buttons at the same time assuming client A won the race to the click.

Comment: Ah. I see. And I see you running into race conditions if you not also implement further measures to mitigate stale data.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods Yes, I would like to avoid race conditions - would the race conditions measures be on the server or on clients? I have updated the post with the latest code snippet. This works but don't know if I am avoid pitfalls etc